# load installed win7 within ubuntu

Tags: windows-7

I have installed Win7 , and after installed Win7,i installed the Ubuntu 13.04

And always using Ubuntu, But some times want to run some application that i installed those on Win7, like Photoshop

I know ubuntu have GIMP that is like photoshop ,but i mostly familiar with Photoshop ,and not have times for learn GIMP

Is it possible to load Win7 that i installed it within Ubuntu?  if yes,exactly how?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What do you mean is it possible to "load Windows 7"? Do you see a choice to boot into Windows or Ubuntu when you first boot your computer?

Comment: Thanks Alaa, yes when i restart my system ,bootloader shown, But i want in ubuntu , run my Win 7 too,at the same time(maybe virtualization).

Comment: It is possible to run Windows within Ubuntu using virtualization, yes, but not run your **actual** installed Windows. You'll have to install a new Windows copy within the virtualization software (that's exactly how I'm doing it). What you can then do is share your partition folders (for example, your actual installed Windows NTFS partition) between the virtual Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: I install the VirtualBox now, and add a virtual machine on it and on add wizard,select Win7, But when start this machine,i get this error:`FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted`,can you help me to know what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you added the Windows 7 CD as the CD in the virtual machine? You need to change the boot order of the virtual machine to boot from the CD.

Comment: No,i should to install Win7 like a really machine, i think Win7 was installed with the wizard automatically

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possibel to boot Windows from Ubuntu. But you can try [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) if you need the "full Windows experience". If you only need some Windows applications (e.g. Photoshop) you can have a look at [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/). From the [Wine Wiki](http://wiki.winehq.org/AdobePhotoshop) : "Photoshop 5 through CS2 and CS4 install and work pretty well on wine."

Comment: I want to load my installed win7 within ubunut

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but quoting "the internet" you should be able to virtualize a DualBoot Windows using Virtual Box

http://geekery.amhill.net/2010/01/27/virtualbox-with-existing-windows-partition/

This links is unfortunately only in german:
http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Dualboot-Windows_virtualisieren